# How can I execute searches via submitting URL (may be with special syntax)?

Tags: url

Can I execute searches via submitting URL (may be with special syntax) rather than typing in words in Google (or other search engine) form?

Answer (score 0):

Typing

```
https://www.google.se/?gfe_rd=cr&safe=off#safe=off&q=mamas%20and%20papas
```

... in the address bar launches the search in firefox.

The same from bash:
`firefox 'https://www.google.se/?gfe_rd=cr&safe=off#safe=off&q=mamas%20and%20papas'`
... note the use of `'`-quotes, as `&` and `#` are special to bash.

`%20` is the hex code for a space. Example: `echo "Test text" | od -t x1z` - will tell you what the codes are for "Test text" and the appended linefeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firefox:

You can define a keyword for any search field. Typing the keyword followed by your search terms into the address bar will then execute a search.

Quoting the instructions from [my answer on Super User](https://superuser.com/a/854673/151741):

> 1. Right-click on any input field.
> 2. Select "Add a keyword for this search…" (or similar).
> 3. Enter the shortcurt (and optionally: edit the generated search URL to include pre-defined search terms).

This will save a bookmark in a folder of your choice. You could manually edit this bookmark to change the keyword or the search URL.

**Example**: If you right-click into the search field of this site, Ask Ubuntu, and associate the keyword `au`, you can enter the following into the address bar to search for "foobar" on Ask Ubuntu:

```
au foobar
```